# getting data from excel sheet put them as dropdowns in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have made an shiny app where I am giving a fileInput where user can input an excel sheet like this: '[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDetz.png)'. I have designed an app which looks like this: '[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHDpL.png)'. My code is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("config","Load Configuration File",accept =c('.xls',',xlsx')),
  actionButton("show_fields","Show Fields"),
  actionButton("estimate","Estimate"),
  uiOutput("ui"),
  textOutput("prod")


)
server <- function(input,output) {

  x <- reactive({read_excel(input$config$datapath)})
  conf <- reactive({x() %>% column_to_rownames(., var = "Rows")})
  design <- eventReactive(input$show_fields, {
    fluidPage(
      numericInput("size","Size",value = 0),
      lapply(1:nrow(conf()),function(i) {
        selectInput(row.names(conf())[i],label = row.names(conf())[i],choices = colnames(conf()))
      })
    )
  })
  output$ui <- renderUI({design()})

  mul <- eventReactive(input$estimate, {
    sapply(1:nrow(conf()), function(j) {
      conf()[row.names(conf())[j],eval(parse(text = paste0("input$",row.names(conf())[j],sep = "")))]
    })
  })

  output$prod <- renderText({paste("Product is: ",prod(mul(),na.rm = TRUE)*input$size)})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

when loading the xls sheet, 'Show Fields' button will show all the Rows as Drop-downs with columns as choices. So at last whatever I choose upon clicking 'Estimate' button Product will be shown of all corresponding values from excel sheet and the inputed size.

So now what I want:
1: All the boxes (numericInput & selectInputs) shall come in two or three columns. The page shall look filled.
2: The actual excel sheet I do have is not exactly I have shown above. It is actually like one you can see in the following image: '[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbiHl.png)'.
Here A-E,U-Z,K-O are drop-downs choices, for corresponding rows(like A-Z for Ram, Shyam etc. , U-Z for Predeep, Sudeep and K-O for Aneeta). I want each such dropdowns and whatever user selects I need to provide the product of all corresponding values from excel sheet along with given Size.

I am trying this out for many days now, and now I am frustated. Somebody please do it.